# How to install Dev Express for Visual C# Express 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I have Visual C# Express 2010 installed on my machine to develop windows application. I read about and have used dev express with visual studio 2010. So I wanted to install dev exprss on my machine and use its tools in Visual C# Express 2010. I have installed dev express but the controls are not showing in the toolbox. I tried adding them in the toolbox options but the dev express tools are not present there. Is dev express not supported to be used with Visual C# Express 2010?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - this isn't a Dev Express limitation per se, but a limitation of the Express SKUs of Visual Studio: they don't allow plugins to be installed. So the same is true for ReSharper, NCrunch etc.

It's one of the differentiation points between the Express range and the commercial editions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok. So i can use dev express tools in visual studio only?

Comment: @maestrosan11: Yes. (It's very possible that you could still use the libraries themselves, but without any design-time support in C# Express.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm going to download visual studio 2010 along with dev expres now.

Comment: @maestrosan11: Any reason for not going straight to VS2013?

Comment: Coz it needs better specs.  My pc isn't that great in specs level. I'm thinking of upgrading it so if I do then maybe I'll go straight for vs 2013.

Comment: @maestrosan11: You're assuming that VS2013 is less efficient than VS2010. I'm not convinced that's true.

Comment: I never said that. I juat said my pc won't be able to run VS2013 efficiently.

Comment: @maestrosan11: Well unless you believe VS2013 is less efficient than VS2010, why would you install VS2010? You should *at least try* VS2013; you can install it side-by-side with VS2010.

Comment: Ok. I'll try VS2013 first.